# How to avoid Abort Dynamic Evaluation error

Tags: front-end

My OS is Windows 7, this error happens in NetModel[], and I can only kill Mathematica.

I've installed a clean Mathematica 11.2. How to avoid this?
Is this a common problem?
Maybe you can reproduce by `Ctrl+A` NetModel's HelpPage, and `Shift+Enter`

If I un-tick `Dynamic updating enabled`, seems something is wrong with the result.

Linux@Ubuntu also has this problem.

---

I think there is something wrong with the FrontEnd in 11.2

`obj=ResourceObject["CIFAR-100"];
obj["Properties"]`

gives no result in 11.2 after waiting a long time and gives Abort Dynamic Evaluation Error

11.1 works fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: (1) `NetModel[]` doesn't seem to be valid syntax, so I assume you did something else. (2) `NetModel` is marked "EXPERIMENTAL" in the docs, which suggests it has not been fully vetted. WRI would probably appreciate feedback, as well as a reliable way to reproduce the problem. (3) I can get the "Kernel not responding..." dialog for a variety of reasons. More information is needed to answer this question, I suspect.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to Edit>Preferences>Advanced>Open Option Inspector .
2. On the left tree , select Cell Options>Evaluation Options .
3. On the right hand side change the "DynamicEvaluationTimeout" Value to whatever you want (eg. infinity or 90)