# Can't open setting of Parallel Kernel Configuration on Mac and Windows after configuring remote kernels

Tags: front-end, parallelization, grid-mathematica

In *Mathematica* 11.3 on Mac and Windows.

Once I've set up the connection with gridMathemtaica's remote kernels. Then I close those machines/kernels and restart my Mathematica.

When I click the Lightweight Grid Button, my frontend will be stuck, and after a few seconds, `$Abort` shows, I can do nothing but force quit Mathematica.

After check the log, I found the problem is because of the request's timeout of some configured remote kernels. So I can solve this problem by delete my settings in the config file. But this is not convenient.

There must be something wrong with Mathematica relate(or similar) with this `Dynamic problem` which is a nightmare [an old dynamic problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162696/how-to-avoid-abort-dynamic-evaluation-error)

[image]

Comment: So you have a Lightweight Grid set up that you're attempting to connect to?

Comment: @user6014 Yes, I've add some set up, I've updated the question.